# Apache PHP API & MySQL AWS Load balancing

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I am building a app and website that has PHP REST API on Apache with MySQl on AWS EC2.

I want to do load balancing, I know I can use two or more EC2 but how MySQL is going to work (How two EC2 will share database)?

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

If you want to have a load balancing feature, it has to be on the web layer and below is the solution for it. Here you have to manage the EC2 and if this goes down then will run into errors in DB layer, hence the solution 2

```
AWS ALB --> EC2 ( Apache, PHP, AZ1 ) --> EC2 ( Mysql )
     \                                  /
      \----> EC2 ( Apache, PHP, AZ2 )  /
```

#### Solution 2

If you go with the RDS with MultiAZ then below is the option for no single point of failure

```
AWS ALB --> EC2 ( Apache, PHP, AZ1 ) --> RDS ( Mysql ) --> with Standby in another AZ
     \                                  /
      \----> EC2 ( Apache, PHP, AZ2 )  /
```

*AZ = Availability Zone*

Comment: Thanks Kartik. Yes, I have hosted REST API PHP on EC2 (2 instance with ELB) and MySql on EC2. If I need load balancing on MySql server will use EBS.

Comment: @Ips, Nice. So you are going to use Elasticbeanstalk right ? Because EBS is kind of confusing here as its full form is Elastic Block Store and ElasticBeanstalk is not having any abbrevation.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/.  May you please suggest me to PHP REST API resource like login API and how to use cognito token for API?